# Why are my User.props always undefined? React-Native and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm working with React-Native and Redux.

I need to access my User state on react redux after an action. 
I try this with a simple console.log after the action on my Component **(console.log(this.props.User))** but it is always undefined.

**This is my Combine Reducer:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'; import User from './userReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    User });
```

**This is my User Reducer:**

```
import {
    REGISTER_USER,
    SIGNIN_USER } from '../types';

export default function(state=INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){

       case  SIGNIN_USER:
       return {
        ...state,
        userData:{
                 uid: action.payload.localId || false,
                 token: action.payload.idToken || false,
                 refreshToken: action.payload.refreshToken || false,
        }
    };
    break;

        default:
            return state
    } }
```

**This is my action:**

```
export function signIn(data){
    const request = axios({
        method:'POST',
        url:SIGNIN, 
        data:{
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
            returnSecureToken:true 
        },
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
        }).then(response => {
            return response.data
        }).catch( e=> {
            console.log(e)
        });

    return {
        type: SIGNIN_USER,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

**Component where I try to get the state after action:**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn } from '../Store/Actions/userActions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';


class LoginComponent extends React.Component {


 state = {
    email:'',
    password:''
  };

      signInUser () {

        try {
          this.props.signIn(this.state).then( () => {
           **console.log(this.props.User)**
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return{
    User: state.User
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps =( dispatch ) => {
  return bindActionCreators({signIn}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LoginComponent);
```

**The response on log just is: undefined**

What is my mistake?? Thanks!

Comment: try accessing this.props.User in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy  I did what you said but the result was the same: Undefined.

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(this.props.User);
  }

Comment: `mapDispatchToProps,mapDispatchToProps`, one should be state and one is dispatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the arguments that you are passing into `connect` method is wrong it  expects `mapStateToProps` first and `mapDispatchToProps` as second 
 parameter. So your code has to be `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginComponent);`

Here is the signature

```
connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])
```

Comment: Something so simple and I never saw it. Thank you very much friend!!